# Creating a table in h2 database using predefined sequence for primary key

Tags: sequence, h2, ddl

I am trying to create a table in an H2 database. How do I specify that the primary key should be generated from a sequence that has been created?

The sequence is called group_seq, and I created it using this statement:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE GROUP_SEQ;
```

So when I create the table, how do I specify that I want my primary key col (ID) to use that sequence?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

If you want to use your own sequence:

```
create sequence group_seq;
create table test3(id bigint default group_seq.nextval primary key);
```

And if not:

```
create table test1(id identity);
```

or

```
create table test2(id bigint auto_increment primary key);
```

All this is documented in the [H2 SQL grammar railroad diagrams](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#create_table).

Comment: how do I specify that id is the primary key?

Comment: @ThomasMueller When I use my custom sequence it doesn't get auto_generated by Hibernate. When I use the auto_increment flag, it works fine. I check in Information_Schema.Sequences and found that the column IS_GENERATED is set to true for system generated sequences but false for custom sequences. Is there a way I can set it to true for custom sequences?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61321952/h2-db-id-nextval 

`id BIGINT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR group_seq not null primary key`