# H2 Db, ID NextVal

Tags: sql, sequence, primary-key, h2

I have a sequence as:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE OWNER_SEQ START WITH 1;
```

I need to trigger this sequence for OWNER table's ID column

```
CREATE TABLE METADATA.OWNER
(
    OWNER_ID           NUMBER  NEXTVAL(METADATA.OWNER_SEQ),
    OWNER_FIRSTNAME    VARCHAR2(100),
    OWNER_LASTNAME     VARCHAR2(100),
    CONSTRAINT OWNER_PK PRIMARY KEY (OWNER_ID)
);
```

I tried several versions of NEXTVAL but all gives error

Comment: http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#sequence_value_expression

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name OWNER_ID           NUMBER  NEXT VALUE FOR METADATA.OWNER_SEQ, I have tried this also

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NUMBER` data type is an Oracle compatibility thing, it shouldn't be normally used in H2 at all, especially for primary keys, this data type is slow. It's much better to use `BIGINT` or `INTEGER` instead.

---

Normally you should not use sequences too if you don't need to share the sequence between multiple tables. You can use an *identity* column. See [the manual](http://h2database.com/html/grammar.html#column_definition).

```sql
OWNER_ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY,
```

You can specify sequence options for identity columns too:

```sql
OWNER_ID BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1),
```

`START WITH 1` is not very useful, however, because this start value will be used by default.

---

But if you have a real reason to use the sequence, you need to specify it as a `DEFAULT` value:

```sql
OWNER_ID BIGINT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR METADATA.OWNER_SEQ,
```

Comment: I am using h2 for test classes. Why number type exist: my original db is oracle

Comment: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: NULL not allowed for column "OWNER_ID"; SQL statement:
`
                    INSERT INTO METADATA.OWNER (
                        OWNER_FIRSTNAME,
                        OWNER_LASTNAME,
                        OWNER_EMAIL,
                        SSO)
                    VALUES 
                (  ?, ?, ?, ?  )  `

Comment: Such exception isn't possible for a column that has a non-null `DEFAULT` value if this column isn't listed in the insert column list. Is it your original command or you edited it somehow? If you incorrectly specify `NULL` for it, you can use `NULL_TO_DEFAULT` like `OWNER_ID NUMBER DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR METADATA.OWNER_SEQ NULL_TO_DEFAULT`.

Comment: CREATE TABLE METADATA.OWNER
(
    OWNER_ID           BIGINT DEFAULT NEXT VALUE FOR OWNER_SEQ NULL_TO_DEFAULT,
    OWNER_FIRSTNAME    VARCHAR2(100),
    OWNER_LASTNAME     VARCHAR2(100),
    OWNER_EMAIL        VARCHAR2(100),
    SSO                NUMBER,
    CREATED_BY         NVARCHAR2(500),
    CREATED_DATE       DATE,
    LAST_MODIFIED_BY   NVARCHAR2(500),
    LAST_MODIFIED_DATE DATE,
    CONSTRAINT OWNER_PK PRIMARY KEY (OWNER_ID)
);

Comment: connection.executeUpdate("""
                    INSERT INTO METADATA.OWNER (
                        OWNER_FIRSTNAME,
                        OWNER_LASTNAME,
                        OWNER_EMAIL,
                        SSO)
                    VALUES 
                ( ${createNSqlParams(4)} ) """,
                        owner.OWNER_FIRSTNAME,
                        owner.OWNER_LASTNAME,
                        owner.OWNER_EMAIL,
                        owner.SSO
                )

Comment: I cannot reproduce this exception with such definition of the table and such insert command with H2 1.4.200. Maybe your application somehow uses another definition of the table from your previous attempts to create it?

Comment: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none fixed when changed to none. thanks